# Run php script every other day

Tags: php, sql

**Problem** 
I would like my PHP code snippet to execute every other day from the date the function is first executed by the user. This isn't that difficult but here are a few constraints that I'd like some help with:

1. The function can only run once within any two day interval to stop the function running multiple times if a user logs on again later.
2. I would like the function to 'catch up' on any missed days. So if 4 days have passed then I would like the function to run twice. The problem here is how to account for odd days (e.g. should the code run twice if 3 days have passed with a day left over?).

**My current (ineffective) solution** 
Currently I use SQL queries to derive variables for an $initial_run and a $last_run of the function. These variables represent the amount of days that have passed, so $initial_run = 6 means six days have passed since the function was executed for the first time (which might be different for different users) and $last_run = 3 means three days have passed since the function was run last time. I have been trying to use this combination of variables to achieve my above desired scenario but here is where I am stuck. The code below is just an example attempt of what I have so far.

```
//in the below example scenario I would want the code to run twice
$initial_run = 6; //6 days
$last_run = 4; //4 days

for ($x = 0; $x < $last_run / 2; $x++) {
    //code needs to 'catch up' on missed days 
    //(i.e. run twice if 4 days have passed since $last_run)

    if ($last_run >= 2 and $initial_run % 2 == 0) {
        //code to only run once within a two day interval
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, I know I could achieve this using SQL events but for my purposes if anyone could offer me a solution within PHP itself that would be great. It doesn't necessarily have to be using only the variables I outlined above, they are just there to illustrate what I have attempted so far. I am open to alternatives but as I said hopefully there is a solution with PHP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ever heard of [cron jobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) / [scheduled tasks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler)? If I were you I'd look into that. Then keep the state of when it has ran etc. in a table so you don't run it twice etc. A PHP-only solution (while technically possible) is not the way to go. A single PHP process isn't meant to be run long-term (let alone for days or months).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The function can only run once within any two day interval to stop the function running multiple times if a user logs on again later.
>
> I would like the function to 'catch up' on any missed days. So if 4
>   days have passed then I would like the function to run twice. The
>   problem here is how to account for odd days (e.g. should the code run
>   twice if 3 days have passed with a day left over?).

Without knowing exactly what you want to achieve with this, your requirements can be addressed quite simple:

Think in "Seconds". You want to run the script every 172.800 seconds (that's two days)

So:

- IF the user logs in for the first time, set a (database) value to the current `datetime`, call it `lastRun`.
- Upon the next login, you calculate the difference in seconds, compared to the stored value `lastRun`.

Perform an integer division on that value by 172.800 and you get the count how often you now need to execute the script (just maths, look at integer division: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html / http://php.net/manual/en/function.intdiv.php):

```
Difference in Seconds | ScriptExecutionTimes | Integer Division "Seconds \ 172800"
< 172.800               Don't run it           0 
[172.800 - 345.599]     Run it Once            1
[345.600 - 518.399]     Run it two times       2
...
```

For every execution increase the value of `lastRun` by 172.800 seconds.

This way, you would never miss any run, no matter if the user doesn't login for 2 or 300 days, or if your server is down for several days.